# Is there a tool which can automatically clean up GlobalSuppressions.cs?

Tags: c#, static-analysis, fxcop, stylecop

I am using FxCop and StyleCop for my projects as well as GlobalSuppressions.cs to suppress some rules. Some projects have changed a lot and some exclusion I did in the past don't apply anymore. The GlobalSuppressions.cs haven't been cleaned up of those exclusions. Is there a tool which can automatically clean up GlobalSuppressions.cs?

Comment: I am pretty sure there is not any tool like that. Why not just clean it by hand?

Comment: I have too many of those files. Cleaning them up is This is too tedious.

Comment: I understand. Anyway, using a powerful text editor that allows regular expressions and perform the same action in more that just one file at a time you could do it. Vim or Notepad++ could help. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such tool available.  The stand-alone FxCop UI tool can help you detect which suppressions are no longer necessary, but there's nothing available for removing the related SuppressMessage attributes from your source code.